# Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value - two separate controllers

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, controller, foreign-keys

a)  This maybe a challenge for me in code igniter but hopefully the experts here could give me some guidance. I have two mysql tables in a database: “users and images.” Users collects registration information from the “Main Controller”:

```
$id = $this->main_model-insertUser($clean);
```

b)  This is tied to the “main_model” as follow:

```
public function insertUser($d)
{  
        $string = array(
            'gender'=>$d['gender'],
            'seeking'=>$d['seeking'],
            'city'=>$d['city'],
            'state'=>$d['state'],
            'country'=>$d['country'],
            'age'=>$d['age'],
            'zodiac'=>$d['zodiac'],
            'username'=>$d['username'],                 
            'email'=>$d['email'],
            'role'=>$this->roles[0], 
            'status'=>$this->status[0], 
            'password'=> '', 
            'last_login'=> ''
        );
        $q = $this->db->insert_string('users',$string);             
        $this->db->query($q);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

c)  Next, I have an image uploading system with its own “Images Controller”.

```
function upload()   {
            $config = array(
            'upload_path' => 'uploads',
            'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
            //'file_name' => $filename,
            'max_size' => 200,
            'max_width' => 1024,
            'max_height' => 768     
        );      
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);        
    if($this->upload->do_upload())
        {
        $file_data = $this->upload->data();                     
        $data['name'] = $file_data['file_name'];
        $data['file'] = $file_data['file_path'];
        $data['file_type'] = $file_data['file_type'];
        $data['file_size'] = $file_data['file_size'];           
        $data['date_uploaded'] = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');           
        $this->images_model->save_image($data);
```

d)  This goes into the database table through the "images_model":

```
Class Images_model extends CI_Model  {
    function save_image($data){     
    $this->db->insert('images', $data);
}
```

e)  Both controllers have worked well individually. The challenge for me is to identify the user from the “users” table when an image is saved to the “images” table. For that, I recently created a foreign key linking the two existing tables. That seems to have gone OK and if you need to see related images, please let me know. However, when I try to load pictures now I get the following database error:  “Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value”.

f)  What I suspect is that this maybe because of the independent controllers. But even though I moved the images code to the “main_view” , I can’t seem to get the pics to save to the “images” table like before. Here is the related code from the view which is also saving to the local folder “uploads.”

```
<?php if($images_model):?>
    <?php foreach($images_model as $images):?>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="well">                  
            <img src="<?php echo base_url()."uploads/".$images->name;?>" alt="" class="img-thumbnail">
```

g)  I would appreciate any help if I am overlooking something or going about this the wrong way:(

Comment: In your whole question where is the part that fetching user and image data from DB?

Comment: @DanishAli The last code I posted is what I have. It fetches ALL the images and displays them in "images view". I can also see them in the database and the related images_id. Part of the problem I think is the fact that it's separate from the user-registration? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think the best way is that save your User Id as a Session data and use it in your upload controller.

Comment: @Ali Qorbani. Will try that. Thanks.

Comment: @Ali Qorbani. That didn't seem to work. I added this code just before uploading an image and I still get that database error. I appreciate the help and if you can think of anything else, please let me know. Thanks.

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
  
  if(!empty($this->session->userdata['user_id'])){
   echo 'you need to be logged in to upload an image.';
            
      }else  
  
  if($this->upload->do_upload())

Comment: can i have your db structure? 
also you can get what db error is showing.

Comment: @AliQorbani.  I found out what's happening and I'm in the process of fixing it. It has to do sessions being set in the users db table and not the images table. And since there are two separate controllers, when I did something to one it affected the other. Since you asked for the db structure, you might have seen it ultimately. I might update this thread when done for anyone who could come across the same problem. If I have other related questions, I'll post them. Thank you for the followup!